# spring @Conditional in SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit

I need to load test properties in production environment when tests is performing by SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

I'm using @Conditional in my spring context to define test/production properties files, like:

```
@Configuration
public class ContextResource {

@Bean
@Conditional(TestApplicationConfiguration.class)
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer testProperties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource [] resources = new Resource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("properties/constants/constants-test.properties")
    };

    placeholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);
    return placeholderConfigurer;
}

@Bean
@Conditional(ProductionApplicationConfiguration.class)
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer productionProperties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource [] resources = new Resource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("properties/constants/constants.properties")
    };

    placeholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);
    return placeholderConfigurer;
}
```

Also i'm using test with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

When *ProductionApplicationConfiguration.class* returned false, *constants-test.properties* is loading and it's normal, but how can I tell my tests to load test properties even if *ProductionApplicationConfiguration.class* returned *true* ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about to make `ProductionApplicationConfiguration` `true` only if `TestApplicationConfiguration` is `false` ?

Comment: It's not possible, cause `ProductionApplicationConfiguration` sets in `true` only when application is running on production server

Comment: It isn't correct answer, as you assert that it is `true` even in test. Anyway it is your code, so how to combine `ProductionApplicationConfiguration` with non-`TestApplicationConfiguration` condition and in test you'll get only the `TestApplicationConfiguration`. Since they are `static` methods, they are loaded and checked by the name order. And even when method `t*` is `true` it can't be applied, because method `t*` has already provided configuration, in case `true`. Cause `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` can be configured only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use different resource (src\main\java\resources and src\test\java\resources) with same names on property files for production and test mode. By default, tests try use property from src\test\java\resources, but if they don't find it, then they will use property from src\main\java\resources.

in 13 intelliji you can mark testResources in module setting.